# jQuery: hide class such that subsequently created elements of that class are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, hide

I've been using the standard method to hide/show a class, namely:

```
$('.myClass').show();  // or .hide() or .toggle()
```

However, if `myClass` is hidden and a new element of the class is created, it is visible because the `.hide()` did not affect it. To work around this, I hide the newly created element if the class is hidden at the time of creation.

Is there a way, however, so that I can hide the class in such a way that it will apply automatically to subsequently created elements?

I'm thinking of the pattern: `$('#container').on('click', '.myClass', function () {...` which attaches the handler to elements created later. Essentially, I want to emulate this with the display property.

Comment: I don't think there is? Closest I can think of is binding something to DOMNodeInserted!

Comment: You could have a `.hidden` class, instead of using `show()/hide()`, and whenever you create a new element, you give it that class initially. Btw, if you are the one that creates and initializes those elements, you can easily just hide them in the initialization process.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas  Yes, I use a `.hidden` class already elsewhere, although I'd get no great value using that here because I'd still have to check if `myClass` elements currently have the class `hidden` and then add the second class (`hidden`) to the newly created element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking your best bet might be to add a class to `#container`, something like this:

```
#container .myClass {

  display: none;

}


#container.with-whatevers .myClass {

  display: block;

}


$( '#container' ).on( 'click', '.myClass', function () {

  $( "#container" ).toggleClass( "with-whatevers" );

} );
```

I'm not sure exactly what your mechanism is for toggling the visibility of the `.myClass` elements -- obviously if they're hidden you can't click on one to toggle their visibility on.

> I'm thinking of the pattern: $('#container').on('click', '.myClass', function () {... which attaches the handler to elements created later.

That does not actually attach the handler to elements created later. It attaches it to `#container`. Then any click event on its descendents will bubble up, and if the target element matches the selector that was passed to `on()`, the handler will be run.

Comment: Ok, well I'd do that with the CSS and just add / remove / toggle that class on `#container`.

Comment: I think I've created a solution at this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/8HHvS The toggle is achieved by clicking another element (i.e., a button equivalent), BTW :)

Comment: I don't get it -- what is that supposed to be showing? You're just adding 2 more visible `.myClass` elements after 3 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, my fiddle didn't work correctly, as pointed out by @adeneo :(  Yours, however, is a really nice solution. I shall accept it!! :)

Comment: I just implemented this solution into the real code, and it is a GREAT solution. Cheers for this - and apologies I took so long to cotton on to your approach :)

Answer (score 1):

`.myClass` should have `display:none` in your CSS. Then, call `.show()` whenever you need it.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/5J5Tt/

Comment: Hmm... Sometimes `myClass` is hidden, and sometimes it ain't. The key is whether it is hidden or not at the time the new element is created.

Comment: @Nick When defined like imsky suggested - any element with that class will be hidden upon creation. Calling `show` or `hide` affects the `style` attribute of the element and not its classes.

Comment: if .myClass{display:none;} is in your CSS, there's no way the browser will paint it into the DOM. Unless you're passing inline CSS rules in your HTML.

Comment: @Caio Bianchi Huh? Paint into the DOM?

Comment: If `.myClass` is arbitrarily visible when you're adding another element with it, check if it's visible with `$(".myClass:visible").length` and if that's true, call `.show()` after inserting the element.

Comment: Imsky - Yes, that's what I'm doing currently. I think the trick may be this: instead of using `$('.myClass').hide();` or `$('.myClass').show();`, I use `$('.myClass').css('display', 'none');` or `$('.myClass').css('display', 'block');` Then when an element is created, it should pick up the jQuery-modified CSS value, right?

Comment: @adeneo If the class is visible, you'll need to `.show()` the new element as it'll be hidden by default. The class "visibility" will be handled by inline styles at that point.

Comment: @Nick You should check if there are visible `.myClass` instances, and if there are, call an extra `.show()` after appending the new element.

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8HHvS/  If I toggle the `display` property on the class, I don't need to use `show` or `hide` at all.

Comment: Yes, but I want to toggle the display property of the class which affects all the element of that class - including those not created yet (which is my goal).

Comment: And that fiddle does not do what it's supposed to do, here's the same fiddle with some logs and more time [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8HHvS/1/) ... setting the display style with JS will only affect elements that already exists in the DOM, not future elements !

Comment: The solution given in this answer will work if you set the display style on element creation (duh), but it still does'nt really do it dynamically for future elements, but it is sort of a solution anyway, and probably as close as you'll get.

Comment: @adeneo  Nice work. Thanks for this. My fiddle doesn't work, as you've demonstrated. I think JMM's solution is the best work around. Thanks, all :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, here's an example of binding to the `DOMNodeInserted` event that will fire whenever an element is inserted into the DOM in most newer browsers :

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {//whenever an element is inserted
    if ($(e.target).is('.myClass')) {          //check if it has the right class
        $(e.target).hide();                    //and hide it if it does
    }
});
```

It won't work in IE as there is no support, I seem to remember having seen some workarounds, so it's probably possible to make it cross browser.

Here's a quick [**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/JzAk7/)

Comment: Yeah, this is more like what I'm looking for. I create a large number of elements, though, so I'm wondering what the efficiency cost will be. The `if` would also have to check if `myClass` is already hidden.

Comment: This is pretty new stuff, and I have'nt really seen much about efficiency, so I think you have to run it in jsperf or test it locally to see for yourself. Adding a check to see it the element is hidden is no problem. This is'nt really something I'd use on something crucial in a production site, but it is fun to play with!

Answer (score 0):

Hide before you add the click event

```
$('.myClass').hide();
```

and then use jQuery's .on() or .delegate() method

```
$('#container').on('click', '.myClass', function(){
  $(this).toggle();
}
```

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding here. There's no click involved. I just used the click handler as an analogous example :)

Comment: why don't you just hide them via CSS then?